# Rxjs - Comparing .map() with map()

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Compare this

```
return this.httpClient.get('https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest', {params: data}).pipe(
            map((x: any) => x.suggestions.map((y) => {
                return {
                    ...y,
                    title: y.text
                };
            })),
        );
```

with this

```
return this.httpClient.get('https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest', {params: data}).pipe(
            map((x: any) => x.suggestions),
            map((y: any) => y.title = y.text)
        );
```

Why these cases are not equal?

The first work as expected, "remove" suggestions property and duplicate property text to title

The second returns me a value... not array

Can I use only map() function instead of .map()?

Comment: Michalis, take account that you has a 'rxjs' map, and a 'array method' map. In the first case, you received an object, you transform this object to only has the propertie "suggestion" (using 'rxjs' map), the property suggestion is an array and you (using 'array' map) trnasform the array. the second, the the first map (is a 'rxjs' map) return the propertie suggestion, and the second map (it's a 'rxjs' map too) try to transform this object and add a propertie "tittle" thats it's equal to the propertie text -that not exist-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is RxJS's pipeable operator map and second one is Array's map function.

Let's have a look at types in your example:

In the first example, you get Observable of object. In this case map operator allows you to transform your object with suggestions array inside of it. Then via Array's map function you map each item from x.suggestions array to new item.

```
const obs$: Observable<{ suggestions: any[] }> = this.httpClient.get('url', { params: data });
obs$.pipe(
  map((x: { suggestions: any[] }) => x.suggestions.map((y) => {
    return {
      ...y,
      title: y.text
    };
  })),
);
```

In the second example after first map operator, you get observable of array. Thus second map operator has an error.

```
const obs$: Observable<{ suggestions: any[] }> = this.httpClient.get('url', { params: data });
const tmp$: Observable<any[]> = obs$.pipe(
  map((x: { suggestions: any[] }) => x.suggestions),
);
tmp$.pipe(
  map((x: any[]) => x.title = x.text) // this line has error: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
)
```

> Since you have Observable of array, you are mapping each item, which
>   is array emitted from the Observable, to the new item.
>
> In case of Array, you are mapping each item, which is object from
>   array, to the new item.

Your thinking was that in the Observable of Array, it would allow you to map items from the array to new items, but it's not the case. It allows you to map the whole Array to whatever you want.

**As a solution to what you wanted to do, have a look at this:**

```
this.httpClient.get('url', { params: data })
  .pipe(
    switchMap(x => x.suggestions),
    map(x => (...x, title: x.text)),
    toArray(),
  )
```

Now, via switchMap, you get Observable of items (instead of Observable of array) and you can map each item as you wish, then transform it back to Observable of array via toArray operator.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you are using `.map()`

```
return this.httpClient.get('https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest', {params: data}).pipe(
                map((x: any) => x.suggestions.map((y) => {
                    return {
                        ...y,
                        title: y.text
                    };
                })),
            );
```

You are using `suggestions.map()`

The `.map()` functions returns and array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

take a look to what map() from rxjs does https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html

Comment: .map() example and map() examples do exact the same thing... They take an array and add or multiply each number

I can't understand the difference